# NSMutableString in an instance method

Tags: objective-c

I’m trying to make a instance method that takes in an NSMutableString and changes individual characters as below. `name` has been set correctly in properties.

With an NSMutableString object in main, the same method in question works fine but I can't get it to work in an instance method. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)changeName:(id)string{
    [self.name replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@"x"];
}
```

Comment: Do you realise that you’re not using the `string` parameter at all? What would be the purpose of that parameter? Does `self.name` get changed after `-changeName:` is invoked? Why do you think the method isn’t working, i.e., what should it do and what are the results?

Answer (score 2):

If it's not working in the instance method, odds are that you're not passing the NSMutableString's pointer to replaceCharactersInRange.  Note that Objective-C methods happily no-op when passed nil pointers.

Use NSLog in your instance method to print out the purported mutable string before and after you attempt to modify it.  Then figure out why the mutable string pointer never got set.